# Tizen 5.5 bluetooth socket communication popup doesn't remember when you select "always allow"

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm working on a Tizen Native app that communicates with an Android app using Bluetooth sockets. The Tizen app acts as the Bluetooth server and is running on a Galaxy Watch Active 2. The Android app acts as the Bluetooth client and is running on a Galaxy S20.

When the Android app connects to the Tizen app, a popup message is shown on the Tizen device that says, "Allow Phone to connect?" with a checkbox for "Always Allow".

I have two Galaxy Watch Active 2 devices, one on Tizen 4.0 and one on Tizen 5.5. On the Tizen 4.0 device, when you check the box for "Always Allow", it remembers it and never asks again for subsequent connections. On the Tizen 5.5 device, it does not remember when you check "Always Allow" and the popup message shows every time the devices connect.

Does anyone know why the Tizen 5.5 device always asks to allow connection even though the "Always allow" box is checked?

Comment: Is it not a feature when you reinstalling application during development?

Comment: You don't have to reinstall the application to see the behavior I described. If for any reason the two devices lose connection and have to reconnect it shows the popup message on the Tizen 5.5 watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue.
When we check the issue, that functionality was missed on Tizen 5.5 wearable device.

We will add the functionality and update it on the next update. (Will share the plan in later)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would upvote it, but I don't have enough reputation. Can you share whether this will be fixed in the next Tizen 5.5 patch or whether I will have to wait for Tizen 6.0 for my watch? Also, if you are able to share an approximate timeline, I would really appreciate it.